# How do I save a link to an email in Gmail?

Tags: gmail

I want to save a hyperlink so I can access an email easily in the future. How can I do this in Gmail?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can create a List to save frequently accessed hyperlinks within Tasks in GMail. You can also star & assign labels to special emails.

Comment: This answer is unclear. How does that get you the link to the email?

Answer (score 2):

Without preview pane: Open the conversation and copy the browser url

With preview pane:

1. Toggle the preview pane with the button on the top right corner
2. Open the conversation
3. Copy the browser url
4. Toggle the preview pane on again

If you don't want the conversation but only a specific e-mail you can disable the conversation view and then the steps above should work the same.

[image: Toggle Preview Pane]

Sources

- [StackExchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/30297/how-to-link-or-share-an-email-in-gmail)
- [labnol.org](https://www.labnol.org/internet/gmail-emails-have-permanent-web-address/6811/)

Answer (score 1):

The only way I've managed to do it (kludgey) is to create a filter that matches to that email.

to:    "some unique part of subject"
And then grab the search URL from the Location bar.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Desciption**

Get the e-mail link with a bookmarklet.

**Installation**

Create a bookmark with the url below

`javascript:window.open("https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#search/rfc822msgid%3A" + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementsByClassName('message_id')[0].innerHTML.slice(4, -4)), "_self");`

**Usage**

1. Open the original message (see image below)
2. Click on the bookmark

**Result**

After clicking the bookmark you will see gmail with one conversation. Open the conversation and the message you are looking for will be expanded while the other messages are collapsed.

**Opening original message**

[image: original message]

**Changes**

13-08-2018 I updated the code to work again.

Answer (score 0):

Simple manual technique that works.

#### Step 1

Copy the rightmost part of the URL when you're on the intended email's page.
You may have reached this email via Search, All, Inbox or some other "listing" page.

Examples:

- Copy the `FMfcgzGtwgjqVpFxzRxxCfWKSXWrtXfp` from `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#search/lg/FMfcgzGtwgjqVpFxzRxxCfWKSXWrtXfp`
- Copy the `FMfcgzGwHVNKRLxWmzqsLhFsqDBJGxwR` from `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#all/FMfcgzGwHVNKRLxWmzqsLhFsqDBJGxwR`

#### Step 2

The shareable URL would be the "all" page URL's initial part with the copied unique string at the end.

Skeleton: `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#all/copied_part_here`

Example: `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#all/FMfcgzGtwgjqVpFxzRxxCfWKSXWrtXfp`

That's it. You can use this URL to access the email.

I'm using the "all" page's URL prefix because it'll work even if the intended email is archived, moved, or deleted (not permanently).