# I CTRL-clicked an email yesterday from my Gmail, today it would NOT load

Tags: gmail

I have a rather frustrating situation with my Gmail and maybe I'm just too dumb to figure out what to do. So while checking my emails one by one, there were emails that I "control-clicked" which opened a new tab showing the thread, so that I can have them open since I cannot reply to them at the moment. The next day of work, I opened all the tabs from my history last session and those email tabs would not load. An example of the link looks like this. the entire page is blank. Yesterday, it was showing the entire message but now it's just blank no matter how many times I refresh. It's not a message ID.

https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?ui=2&view=btop&ver=1nsgzyoo2q6aj&search=inbox&type=p4&th=%23thread-f:(i erased this part for security reasons, it's a 19-digit number)&cvid=5

Not sure if it makes sense.

I figured on just going back to all my emails again but I find it a pain doing that because I have like 25 of those tabs I ctrl-clicked and I have more than 5,000 emails which will take me eternity to go though each. Thank you very much to whoever answers.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Have you opened gmail.com before opening the messages from the history last session?

Comment: yes. I have a gmail.com opened on a different tab while loading those other tabs I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

The URL includes several parameters that aren't mentioned in the official Gmail Help Center so we really don't for how they work and for how long they will be working, and by the other hand, Google might disable these parameters at any time without making any announcement.

The best might be to use one of the built-in functions:

**Use star feature** By default the star feature has a single simbol, but it's possible to enable up to 12 symbols. For details see [Star emails](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/5904?hl=en)

**Use the Snooze feature**. This feature makes emails to appear on top of the Inbox at certain time. For details see [Snooze emails until later](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7622010?hl=en)

**Use labels**. This feature helps to organize emails. For details see [Create labels to organize Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/118708?hl=en)

**Use the task feature**. Tasks could be create for Gmail, this will make that the selected Gmail conversation be linked to the task. For details on creating task from an email see [Add or edit a task](https://support.google.com/tasks/answer/7675838)

If you still want to use use a URL see this other question for several options about how to get a [*permalink*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permalink) for Gmail conversation / thread -> [How do I save a link to an email in Gmail?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/21020/88163)